# Can I edit an existing order in Expresso Store?

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to edit a person's order through the backend? For example, if I need to correct a person's name or address or want to change a product in their order.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this from the Store CP. You would need to edit the orders directly in the database (keep in mind this won't recalculate order totals if you change the items/shipping charges).

The best way to do this would be to write a simple module to let you update the order. I believe someone may already be working on a third party module to let you do this. I've also just added it to our [feature requests](https://exp-resso.com/store/support) page, so feel free to add your support.

Comment: We're currently building a module to edit the shipping costs on existing orders (for manual calculations) - This will in turn update totals / taxes etc. Changing / adding / removing items certainly won't make our 1.0 release though but maybe it could be added later.

Comment: Thanks guys I've voted up the feature request. Most of the shopping carts I've used before had this feature out of the box to manually edit order details through the CMS. Definitely  would like to see this in a future release. I'll have to edit the database manually, which isn't too bad in my case as I just have one product and I am managing the website itself. However, if I was selling a large number of products and had a large number of buyers I don't think I would use expresso store because of the lack of this feature. That said, if there was a module then I might be tempted to purchase it

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly a nice to have. The only reason it hasn't been added yet is because we have received very few requests for it and developing other features has taken priority.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil Hey Adrian, we've internally created fully fledged internal editing capabilities. I'm really not too interesting in selling it as an add-on, and would much prefer it be merged into the official Express-Store. Is this something you'd consider?

Comment: @MichaelP yes, we could certainly take a look at it. Send an email to support@exp-resso.com and we will follow up.

Comment: @MichaelP I have a customer who's asking for the ability to edit orders. Did your add-on ever get used by the guys at Expresso Store or is it available anywhere?